# Rails submit remote form onclick of radio button

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that submits when you chose a radio button (below).  Currently the page refreshes when it submits and I'd like to use Jquery and remote submission so it doesn't refresh.  Any idea where to start with this?

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :orderstatus_id, :as => :radio, :label => false do %>
        <% current_user.account.orderstatuses.order(:status_order).each do |os| %>
        <p id="invoice-color-select">
                <%= f.radio_button :orderstatus_id, os.id, :class => 'selector', :onclick => "this.form.submit();" %>
                <%= f.label "#{os.name}", :style => "background: ##{os.color}", :class => 'status' %>
    </p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <div style="margin-top:20px">
        <% if !current_user.account.has_plan? || current_user.account.plan_key== "ultra" %>
            <a class="fancybox" href="#editstatus">Edit</a>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out bcackerman??  I'm trying to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this into my view:

```
<%= f.radio_button :orderstatus_id, os.id, :class => 'selector', :onclick => "this.form.submit();" %>
```

You can see the `:onclick` portion here.